# Only show html on certain days w/php

Tags: php, if-statement

I only want to show some html on certain days of the week. I think I am very close, but cannot get this to work. Thanks for the help.

```
<?php
$dayofweek = date('l');
$daystoshow = array('Thursday','Sunday','Wednesday');

if ($dayofweek == $daystoshow) {
echo "show this";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? PS: you better use `N` or `w` flag

Comment: Take a look at [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: [`in_array`](http://www.php.net/in_array)

Comment: try `in_array($dayofweek, $daystoshow);`

Comment: You're comparing `$dayofweek` that is a string value with `$daystoshow` that is an array

Comment: Seriously? A downvote? I don't think I did anything wrong, and my question was clear. I am so tired of my rep being ruined by big-headed users on here with high rep. It's not fair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check to see if a value in in an array:

```
if (in_array($dayofweek, $daystoshow)) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am not great at php... still learning. I almost had it! Now I know you cannot compare a string value to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Allright:

Lets use `PHP` date function

Do you want to show it only during a particular month ?

```
$date = date("m");
if ($date == "01") { // only on january
//output
}
```

Do you want to show it only during a particular day ?

```
$date = date("d");
if ($date == "01") { //Only on the first of the month
//output
}
```

Do you want to show it only during particular dayS ?

```
    $days = array("01","11","28");
    $date = date("d");
    if (in_array($date,$days)) { //Only 01,11,28
    //output
    }
```

Do you want to show it only during particular days of week ?

```
    $days = array("Thursday","Sunday","Wednesday");;
    $date = date("l");
    if (in_array($date,$days)) { 
    //output
    }
```

Do you want to show it only during a particular year ?

```
$date = date("Y");
if ($date == "2014") { //Only on 2014
//output
}
```

Comment: Although a nice exercise, this doesn't actually address their issue at all.

Comment: Now it does with the fourth example, and provides some samples for the future :)

Comment: I appreciate all of the other examples and explanations. Thank you.